# AWS Route 53 domain to directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS, so bear with me.

Using the same Elastic Beanstalk, I'd like to point:

- `example.com` to `/var/www/html/example`
- `anothersite.com` to `/var/www/html/anothersite`
- `yetanotherdomain.com` to `/var/www/html/yetanotherdomain`

Is this possible?

I had three Beanstalks, three instances, and three elastic IPs running, but that seemed quite expensive.